# Laravel `lt` and 'gt' validation rules only if target fields are present

Tags: laravel, validation, eloquent, option-type, rules

I have two integer fields to validate in my request, `min_height` and `max_height`, with both being optional but having `min_height` to be lower than `max_height` and `max_height` hanving to be (of course) greater than `min_height`.

Using the validation rule as follow

```
'min_height' => ['nullable', 'integer', 'lt:max_height'],
'max_height' => ['nullable', 'integer', 'gt:min_height'],
```

This of course gives me error when either one is present but not the other, since the `lt`/`gt` validation rule check against a `null` request field.

How can i have `lt`/`gt` being checked only if the other field is present?
Is there a way to achieve this with built-in validation rules or do i have to implement a custom validator?

#### UPDATE

Probably i have not been clear enough: **my two field are both nullable and independent of each other**, so it's ok to receive `min_height` and not `max_height` and vice versa: this makes rules like `required_with` not suitable 
 for my use case.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#rule-required-if

check for this

Comment: @Rafee can you explain? I don't need the `required_if` rules, my fields are independent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @vinayak-sarawagi said, there are no built-in solution for this use case, so a custom validation rule have to be implemented to check for the optionally null parameter before actually compare values.

Answer (score 3):

You can try using [required_with](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#rule-required-with) conditional rule. For example your condition will

```
'min_height' => 'required_with:max_height|lt:max_height',
'max_height' => 'required_with:min_height|gt:min_height',
```

Comment: i updated my question to be more clear: rules like `required_with` are not suitable for my use case

Comment: Okay. Then in that case you will have to probably make your own custom **optional_lt** and **optional_gt** validation functions.

Comment: that's what i was afraid of, but ok, i'll get with it

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and here is an elegant solution that works and does not require creating a custom rule. Just use plain old PHP. Check if the field you compare to is filled and only then add your validation rule:

```
'min_height' => [ 
    'nullable',
    'integer', 
     request()->filled('max_height') ? 'lt:max_height' : ''
     ],
'max_height' => [
    'nullable', 
    'integer', 
     request()->filled('min_height') ? 'gt:min_height' : ''
    ],
```

If you have your rules inside a FormRequest you can use `$this->filled('min_height')` instead of `request()->filled('min_height')`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sometimes` on the first parameter. take a look at:
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#conditionally-adding-rules

Comment: The `exclude_if` rule skip the entire validation of the given field (if got it correctly), but what i want is to skip just the `lt`/`gt` rules, keeping the `integer` one